# Functions not executing in Python

Tags: python

I have a program that runs when the functions have not been defined. When I put code into a function, it does not execute the code it contains. Why? Some of the code is:

```
def new_directory():

    if not os.path.exists(current_sandbox):
        os.mkdir(current_sandbox)
```

Comment: So, how you call this function ?

Comment: Do you have the rights to create that directory?

Comment: Try adding `print 'here'` at the first line in the function. To see if control is going there or not. It might turn out that `not os.path.exists(current_sandbox)` is giving False every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem 1 is that you define a function ("def" is an abbreviation of "define"), but you don't call it.

```
def new_directory(): # define the function
 if not os.path.exists(current_sandbox):  
     os.mkdir(current_sandbox)

new_directory() # call the function
```

Problem 2 (which hasn't hit you yet) is that you are using a global (`current_sandbox`) when you should use an argument -- in the latter case your function will be generally useful and even usefully callable from another module. Problem 3 is irregular indentation -- using an indent of 1 will cause anybody who has to read your code (including yourself) to go nuts. Stick to 4 and use spaces, not tabs.

```
def new_directory(dir_path):
    if not os.path.exists(dir_path):  
        os.mkdir(dir_path)

new_directory(current_sandbox)
# much later
new_directory(some_other_path)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is actually a definition of a `new_directory` function. It won't be executed unless you make a call to `new_directory()`.

So, when you want to execute the code from your post, just add a function call like this:

```
def new_directory():

 if not os.path.exists(current_sandbox):
   os.mkdir(current_sandbox)

new_directory()
```

I am not sure if that's the behavior you expect to get.

Comment: But generally much better to put that in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block so it won't get executed when the module is merely imported by another.

Comment: @Peter Hansen: Indeed the OP needs to move through crawl, walk, run stages, but right now he's stone cold motionless and needs kick-starting. The thought that his script might also be used as a module may quite possibly not have occurred to him.

Answer (score 1):

```
def new_directory():  
  if not os.path.exists(current_sandbox):  
     os.mkdir(current_sandbox)

new_directory()
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.