# Turtle graphics automatically closes whenever i try to run it

Tags: python

Whenever i try to run this code, it automatically closes. Any help?

```
import turtle

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("lime")
player.speed(1)


def makeShape (NumSides):
    for i in range (NumSides):
        player.forward(100)
        player.left(360.0/NumSides)
```

Comment: you need to call your function `makeShape()` In your code you are defining it but never calling it

Comment: can't get it. pls explain clearly :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [functions not executing python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958134/functions-not-executing-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function

If the window closes is because you need to call done() at the end

You can check a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) so you get an example of a minimal program.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done) of done() you will see it says:

> Must be the last statement in a turtle graphics program. Must not be
> used if a script is run from within IDLE in -n mode (No subprocess) -
> for interactive use of turtle graphics.

```
from turtle import *

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("lime")
player.speed(1)


def makeShape (NumSides):
    for i in range (NumSides):
        player.forward(100)
        player.left(360.0/NumSides)


# here you need to call the function and pass the number of sides you want
# example to make a square
makeShape(4)

done()
```